# Getting value from DropDownList in MVC3.. better way than binding the ID to another field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering if there is another way to express the following bit of code. The code works as expected, but I have an issue with how it defines my naming conventions.

```
//Model.cs:
[DisplayName("Device Manufacturer")]
public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> DeviceManufacturer { get; set; }
public int SelectedManufacturerID { get; set; }

//Model.ascx:
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedManufacturerID, new SelectList(Model.DeviceManufacturer, "Key", "Value"))%>
```

Now, whenever the selected list item is changed -- the new value is stored in SelectedManufacturerID. I am able to receive the value in my controller like so:

```
int selectedID = model.SelectedDataCenterID;
```

**However,** I am unhappy with the fact that MVC gives my select list the ID 'SelectedManufacturerID' when it is not an ID field -- it is a select list. Clearly this is occurring to support the binding to the SelectedManufacturerID field.

If I wish to work with my select list client-side, I now have code such as:

```
$('#SelectedManufacturerID').change(function(){
    console.log("OnSelectedIndexChanged!");
});
```

This jQuery is very unclear. There is no indication that SelectedManufacturerID is a select DOM element. It seems impossible to have proper naming conventions using the MVC conventions at the top of this post. Does anyone else feel this way? Do I have other options?

Comment: I don't feel this is a real problem, you can rename the list to `DeviceManufacturerList` instead of `DeviceManufacturer` and the selected value as `DeviceManufacturer` instead of `SelectedManufacturerID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want,you can update the ID or other html attributes of the dropdown by using a different [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703436%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of `DropDownListFor` helper method. Here you can pass html attributes as the last parameter.

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedManufacturerID,
             new SelectList(Model.DeviceManufacturer, "Key", "Value"),
                                          new { @id="ManufacturerList"})%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `select#SelectedManufacturerID` instead.